# Custom dimensions property with multiple entries in Azure Applications Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

my logs contain in customDimensions multiple entries.

```
{"MessageType":"EventLog","Properties":"{\"Action\":\"Manual Trigger\",\"City\":\"New York\"}","AppBuild":"22"}
```

How do I extract the entries in "Properties" and put them in separate columns?

```
{\"Action\":\"Manual Trigger\",\"City\":\"New York\"}
```

| Action | City |
| --- | --- |
| Manual Trigger | New York |

For some reason, the entries in "Properties" do not have the same order. Sometimes "City" can be first.

I could extract properties, but this is only halfway

```
let events = customEvents
 | extend properties = tostring(customDimensions["Properties"])
```

or

```
let events = customEvents
 | extend properties = tostring(customDimensions.Properties)
```

Splitting the result could work, except, that the entries do not have the same order for each log entry.

Comment: Is this really how the data looks like - `"Properties":"{"Action"`? If that's the case, `customDimensions["Properties"]` cannot be working.

Comment: You are absolutely right, actually it looks like this: 
"Properties":"{\"Action\":\"Manual Trigger\"...

Comment: I just tried with

```let events = customEvents
 | extend type=parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.Properties))
 | mvexpand type```

and received for each entry a new row. Cloud actually work like this. Now I could filter for "Action"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the [`bag_unpack()` plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin).

for efficiency, make sure you specify the output schema (in this case `(Action: string, City: string)`)

```
datatable(customDimensions:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"MessageType":"EventLog","Properties":"{\"Action\":\"Manual Trigger\",\"City\":\"San Francisco\"}","AppBuild":"21"}),
    dynamic({"MessageType":"EventLog","Properties":"{\"Action\":\"Manual Trigger\",\"City\":\"New York\"}","AppBuild":"22"})
]
| extend properties = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.Properties))
| evaluate bag_unpack(properties) : (Action: string, City: string)
```

| Action | City |
| --- | --- |
| Manual Trigger | San Francisco |
| Manual Trigger | New York |